# copyValuesToRange returns nothing if startColumn is integer

Tags: google-apps-script

Writing a script where a cell with a formula is overwritten with value shown in the same cell. The following code **WORKS** (however formatted for readability):

```
var TargetHistorySheetRow = 95; //some arbitrary integer
var HistorySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("History");

HistorySheet.getRange(TargetHistorySheetRow, HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1)
   .copyValuesToRange(
                      HistorySheet, 
                      HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1, 
                      HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow
                      );
```

There is a repeating piece of code throughout (`HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1;`) for finding a specific column number dynamically. For readibility, I moved this snippet to a variable and used the variable throughout instead. The following update **DOES NOT WORK** and changes the target cell to a blank

```
var TargetHistorySheetRow = 95; //some arbitrary integer
var HistorySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("History");
var HistorySheetAllocatedColumn = HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1;

HistorySheet.getRange(TargetHistorySheetRow, HistorySheetAllocatedColumn)
   .copyValuesToRange(
                      HistorySheet, 
                      HistorySheetAllocatedColumn, 
                      HistorySheetAllocatedColumn, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow
                      );
```

However, if I change only the startColumn parameter of copyValuesToRange back, it **WORKS** again:

```
HistorySheet.getRange(TargetHistorySheetRow, HistorySheetAllocatedColumn)
   .copyValuesToRange(
                      HistorySheet, 
                      HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("Allocated")+1, 
                      HistorySheetAllocatedColumn, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow, 
                      TargetHistorySheetRow
                      );
```

Changing that parameter to a static value (eg: 7), doesn't work either. What's going on here?

Comment: It might be helpful to share your spreadsheet.  It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem in a new public sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10QlZV8MHJxfnNhcHaWLv402W0FDpdelilFWKDxsbzoI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

The behaviour you describe here is very interesting. When you call `Range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`, according to the documentation, the `column`, `columnEnd`, `row` and `rowEnd` parameters [should all be Integers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend).

Now after some testing, you can see that the following line returns `number`:

```
typeof HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC")
```

As does:

```
typeof HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1
```

***However*** when you log `HistorySheetTargetColumn` and `HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1` separately, you get the following result:

```js
var HistorySheetTargetColumn = (HistorySheet.getRange("1:1")
                                            .getValues()[0]
                                            .indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1);

Logger.log('variable = ' + HistorySheetTargetColumn); // => variable = 3
Logger.log('method call = ' + HistorySheet.getRange("1:1")
                                          .getValues()[0]
                                          .indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1);
                                          // => method call = 21
```

You can see that the 21 concatenation happens because `HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC")` is being evaluated ***as a string*** before the `+` operator, meaning that after the `+ 1` the value becomes 21 and not 3, as it should be if it was being evaluated as an integer.

It therefore appears that when you use `HistorySheetTargetColumn` in `.copyValuesToRange()` is is re-evaluating `HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1` each time, getting `2` from the `indexOf()` return *as a string*, and then concatenating the `1` at the end. This is why your cell is evaluating to be blank - because Cell `A21` is blank.

#### Workaround:

You can fix this in the mean time by adding parenthesis around `HistorySheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1` on assignment:

```js
var HistorySheetTargetColumn = (HistorySheet.getRange("1:1")
                                            .getValues()[0]
                                            .indexOf("ColumnHeaderC") + 1);
```

#### Reporting the Issue:

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd) reading string instead of integer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147127259)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `Range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)
- [w3schools - JavaScript Array indexOf() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)
- [MDN web docs - Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147127259)

  - [Range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd) reading string instead of integer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147127259)

Comment: That's a doozy, thanks! I repped the issue on Google Issue Tracker for you. The workaround with adding parentheses around the variable declaration doesn't seem to work for me in both the original document and the sample one.